# Getting an update syntax error from a SqlDataSource in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2010, sqldatasource

I keep getting a syntax error when trying to run an update query in a `SqlDataSource` in asp.net.

```
UPDATE User 
SET userName = @userName, 
    password = @password, 
    UserType = @UserType, 
    datejoined = @datejoined, 
    email = @email, 
    loggedIn = @loggedIn, 
    picFilePath = @picFilePath 
WHERE 
    userName = @userName
```

All the tables are saved in a MS Access 2010 file and all the parameters are saved in session, but I don't think it's relevant since this is just a syntax error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there really a **space** in here? `loggedIn = @ loggedIn` - should there be a space between the `@` and the `loggedIn` ??

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that one.

Comment: Well, I still get a syntax error for some reason.

Comment: Not sure - in SQL Server, `User` is a reserved keyword - so in SQL Server, you need to use `[User]` for your table name instead. Not sure if that applies to MS Access, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` and `password` are [MS Access reserved words](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx), I'd suggest using square brackets for the table name and all of the column names:

```
UPDATE [User]
SET [userName] = @userName, 
    [password] = @password, 
    [UserType] = @UserType, 
    [datejoined] = @datejoined, 
    [email] = @email, 
    [loggedIn] = @loggedIn, 
    [picFilePath] = @picFilePath 
WHERE 
    [userName] = @userName
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently password is a reserved keyword too.

Comment: If you use a table name and (ideally) an alias, you can avoid nearly all reserved word problems and it is much more SQL-friendly eg `SELECT t.User FROM MyTable t`

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a **space** in here?

```
loggedIn = @ loggedIn
            ^
            |
            +---> should there be a space here?
```

I don't think there should be a space between the `@` and the `loggedIn`

In addition: in SQL Server, `User` is a reserved keyword - so in SQL Server, you need to use `[User]` for your table name instead. Not sure if that applies to MS Access, too.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it and I still get a syntax error for some reason.